# HashMap.get() returns null even though element exists

Tags: java

From within my code, I add an entry to a HashMap. Later, when trying to get the element by its key, it returns null.

Can't post images yet, but after debugging this is what it says:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf1bW.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxxEI.png

Please help me solve this really weird error!

EDIT: Since you requested, these are the addEntry() and getEntry() methods and the place in code where they are called:

```
backgroundActor = new BackgroundActor(new BackgroundGraphicsComponent());
backgroundActors.addEntry(backgroundActor, "Background");
borderActor = new BorderActor(new BorderPhysicsComponent(), new BorderGraphicsComponent());
backgroundActors.addEntry(borderActor, "Border");

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T getEntry(String key) {
        if (gameObjects.get(key) != null) {
            return (T) gameObjects.get(key);
        }
        else throw new NullPointerException(); // this is where it fails
    }

    @Override
    public void addEntry(T gameObject, String key) {
        if (gameObject != null) gameObjects.put(gameObject, key);
        else throw new NullPointerException();
    }
```

EDIT2: **Solved.** The problem was with the put() method of `HashMap` that takes as its first argument the key and then the value.
Thanks to Nizil and user1498360!

Comment: Please post the relevant code. This image doesn't help solve your problem.

Comment: Have you read the [JavaDoc of `Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) at least once? If not, then why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `put` method of `Map` take as first argument the key, then the value.

So in your `addEntry` method, you should do:

```
gameObjects.put(key, gameObject);
```

Instead of

```
gameObjects.put(gameObject, key);
```

This explain why your debugger print `{BackgroundActor=Background, BorderActor=Border}` instead of `{Background=BackgroundActor, Border=BorderActor}`

Answer (score 1):

Please change:

```
if (gameObject != null) gameObjects.put(gameObject, key);
```

to:

```
if (gameObject != null) gameObjects.put(key, gameObject);
```

I hope this will solve your problem.